# Onclick add images to a div in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax, codeigniter

I am facing a weird problem. When I click on the button with `id="fashion"` I am writing the images into a div `cashback_merchant`. Here I specified `float:left`. But my images are not following this part and they are getting displayed one below the other.

This is the CSS part:

```
<style>
  .cashback_merchant {
      height: 100px;
      width: 220px;
      float: left;
      padding: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
      margin-top: 10px;
      border-radius: 10px;
 }
</style>
```

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="cashback_merchant">
</div>
```

This is my ajax part:

```
 $.post('get_category', data = { type : 'Fashion' }, function( data ) {
    $.each( data, function( item, i) {
        var image_path = "<?php echo base_url();?>assets/images/"+i.image_name;                         
        $(".cashback_merchant").hide().append('<img class = "image" 
        src="'+image_path+'"/>').fadeIn('slow');        
    });                                   
 },'json');
```

Comment: Do you have a live demo? Like on jsfiddle.net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The float is on the wrapper, not on the images. The reason the images get displayed beneath eachother is probally because your images are bigger thatn 220px (or atleast two of them nexto eachother are bigger) so it starts on a new line.

```
.cashback_merchant .image
  {
   float:left;
 }
```

or if the whole class was ment for the images:

```
.cashback_merchant .image
  {
  height: 100px;
  width: 220px;
  float:left;
  padding:10px;
  margin-left:10px;
  margin-top:10px;
  border-radius:10px;
 }
```

Comment: Anyways, mark as answer, and upvote if you think the answer was usefull. Welcome on SO :)